# Cannot get rid of tmpfs

Tags: linux, arch-linux, tmpfs

Using Arch Linux - 4.14.4

`/dev`, `/run`, `/dev/shm`, `/sys/fs/cgroup` and `/run/user/1000` is using as tmpfs on my system, I want to disable tmpfs due to some reasons.

```
[~] df -h                                                                                                                                                                                      
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
dev             3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev
run             3.8G  1.2M  3.8G   1% /run
/dev/sda1       234G   51G  181G  22% /
tmpfs           3.8G   14M  3.8G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           768M   24K  768M   1% /run/user/1000
[~] systemctl status tmp.mount                                                                                                                                                                 
● tmp.mount
   Loaded: masked (/dev/null; bad)
   Active: inactive (dead)
[~] cat /etc/fstab                                                                                                                                                                             
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
#
UUID=a960b0ab-473a-4f6b-98ad-ca63c421f8c5 / ext4 defaults,noatime,discard 0 1
[~] cat /etc/mtab | grep tmpfs                                                                                                                                                                 
dev /dev devtmpfs rw,nosuid,relatime,size=3923892k,nr_inodes=980973,mode=755 0 0
run /run tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,mode=755 0 0
tmpfs /dev/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev 0 0
tmpfs /sys/fs/cgroup tmpfs ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755 0 0
tmpfs /run/user/1000 tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=786116k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=100 0 0
```

Comment: What would you like to replace them with?

Comment: `tmpfs` support is compiled into the kernel.  if you're trying to completely disable `tmpfs` you'll want to recompile the kernel with `CONFIG_TMPFS=n` (perhaps start with editing `config` in [the official Arch kernel package](https://git.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/tree/trunk?h=packages/linux)).  i don't know what will break if you boot a standard Arch install with such a kernel.

Answer (score -2):

See this
https://www.removemalwarevirus.com/know-about-nsh4f98-tmpfs-and-its-characteristics

Read this post this can help you to understand about the nsh4f98 malware

Comment: The link you pasted regards Windows OS not Linux/UNIX